# Eevee render casting blocky shadow

Tags: rendering

I'm having issues with my eevee render having weird blocky shadows.
This doesnt happen in cycles.

I should mention that the there is a clear box that goes around the garment you see, which I think is casting the shadow.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image: Eevee Render blocky shadows]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

Comment: in the Render panel, have you tried to increase the Sampling for the Viewport? Also check the values under Render > Shadows (like Cube Size). And as Rick T says, you could share your file (juste the light and the 2 objects that make the shadow)

Comment: @RickT Thank you! I will give this a shot now.

Comment: @moonboots Thanks! I will also give this a shot. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a motion blur artefact, and increasing the *Max Blur* value seems to fix it:

[image]