# 3D view looks noisy in Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

user148869 asks a question about [his file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ybknwgVN/) on [this page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264846/eevee-render-casting-blocky-shadow). I think I've answered, but I have another question about this file. Why does the viewport look noisy? Eevee is the render engine that is currently selected:

[image]

Comment: Check the **Blend Mode** of the materials of the affected objects at Material Properties Panel > Settings sub-panel. I'm hazarding a guess it's it, but I don't want to download the file just to look at it.

Comment: wow yes I thought it had to do with the Render panel  ^^  please propose your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @Rhaenys (see comments) for this answer:

> Check the Blend Mode of the materials of the affected objects at Material Properties Panel > Settings sub-panel.

Thanks Rhaenys!

*Note: I am only posting this answer because Rhaenys never created one, even after 4 months. This way, this question can be solved.*